# Select any position then Switch Player in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that allows me to select any position on the board then switch players. I had attempted to write a for loop but either nothing appeared or all the positions filled with "X". I believe I need to stop the loop from iterating once a position is selected and created another for loop for the addEventLister. (JS Newbie- Thanks!)

```
function player1(){
    for(var i = 0; i<boardslots.length;i++) //Iterate through all the positions
    if(boardSlots[i].classList !== "x" || "o"){ //Check to see if space is occupied
         boardSlots[i].classList.add("x"); //Add X
         player2(); //Switch to player 2     
    }
}

//Player 2 Selects O
function player2(){
    for(var i = 0; i<boardslots.length;i++)
    if(boardSlots[1].classList !== "x" || "o"){
         boardSlots[1].classList.add("o");
         player1();
    }

}

boardSlots[i].addEventListener("click",player1); //Select Position on the board
```

Comment: `if(boardSlots[i].classList !== "x" || "o")` doesn’t work in a few ways. `classList` is not a string and the or operator can’t be used like that. `!boardSlots[i].classList.contains("x") && !boardSlots[i].classList.contains("o")`, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, the program seems to be ignoring condition and still adding the class

Comment: Actually that worked. It prevents me from selecting a position if occupied. Thanks

Comment: What are all the `boardSlots` inside?  Do you have something like a `<div class="board">` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
function move1(){
    if(count % 2 === 0 && !this.classList.contains("x") && !this.classList.contains("o")){
         this.classList.add("x");
         count++;
         // this.removeEventListener('click', move1); 
    } else if(!count % 2 === 0) {
        this.classList.add("o");
        count++;

    }
}

// Add Event Listener To Each Position
boardSlots[0].addEventListener("click",move1); 
boardSlots[1].addEventListener("click",move1); 
boardSlots[2].addEventListener("click",move1); 
boardSlots[3].addEventListener("click",move1); 
boardSlots[4].addEventListener("click",move1); 
boardSlots[5].addEventListener("click",move1); 
boardSlots[6].addEventListener("click",move1); 
boardSlots[7].addEventListener("click",move1); 
boardSlots[8].addEventListener("click",move1); 
boardSlots[9].addEventListener("click",move1); 

};
```

Comment: `!count % 2 === 0` should probably be `count % 2 !== 0`; it will still work as-is, but only coincidentally.